# Add custom session data to jsoup POST request in clojure

Tags: testing, clojure, jsoup

I am testing my first clojure ring application with `midje` and `jsoup`.
The app uses [ring-session](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj) to add `session` for logged-only pages.
Session is not a cookie, neither part of the header of the request and I dont know how to add it to perform a post request correctly on logged pages...

A **POST** request in `jsoup` is something like:

```
(-> (Jsoup/connect "http://localhost:3001/sendto")
    (.userAgent "...")
    (.header "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    (.data "amount" amount)
    (.data "to" email)
    (.data "sendto-submit" "Send")
    (.post))
```

Altough this will not work when trying to perform a request against a logged-only url.

I'd have to add the session object, that in my case is something like:

```
{:session {:auth {:email "name@email.com"}}}
```

to the request, but so far neither `(.cookie)` nor `(.data)` worked...

Any help is suuuuper welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the server side config, it's hard to give exact advice, but you have to remember the cookie you get on login and send it with the requests.

What you see on the server as `{:session {:auth ,,,}}` is the result of the session wrapper loading server side stored data into the request.

So basically:

1. you send a request, that starts a session (e.g. your login)
2. the server sends you a cookie back and stores informations about the login in it's session storage
3. you send a request, that includes that cookie
4. the server looks the cookie up in the session storage and injects the data associated with it in the request.

See [the source/doc](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj#L77)